# Query a one primary key two foreign relationship

Tags: sql-server

I have two Tables, Team (teamID(pk), teamName) and Fixture(fixtureID, TeamA_ID(fk), TeamB_ID(fk)) how do I query the fixture table and get the names of both teams.

Comment: Anytime you have a table referring back to the same table on a key, you need multiple joins back to that table. and to keep things straight you have to alias the table names and column names referenced.

Answer (score 1):

You need to join to the Fixture table twice. Something like this.

```
select *
from Fixture f
join Team t1 on t1.TeamID = f.TeamA_ID
join Team t2 on t2.TeamID = f.TeamB_ID
```

Comment: I'd also recommend aliasing the columns in the select otherwise knowing which teamName value ties to which team could be challenging.  `Select t1.teamName as TeamName1, T2.teamName as TeamName2`

Comment: @xQbert absolutely. And not sure why I didn't alias the columns in the join....I never do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can join to the same table more than once.

And if those foreign keys in Fixture can contain NULL values, then by using a LEFT JOIN (instead of an INNER JOIN) you'll still get all from the Fixture table.

```sql
select 
  AB.fixtureID, 
  A.teamName as TeamA_Name, 
  B.teamName as TeamB_Name
from Fixture AB
left join Team A on (A.TeamID = AB.TeamA_ID)
left join Team B on (B.TeamID = AB.TeamB_ID)
```